# Slope of a curve with a parametric equation

Tags: calculus

I couldn't understand what is meant here :

Consider the curve parametrised by the equation :

$$L=(x(t),y(t))$$

Then $$\frac{\frac{dx}{dt}}{\frac{dy}{dt}}$$

Is the slope of the curve. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$

Comment: Okay, thanks!! .

Answer (score 0):

The slope at some given point is, as we know:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$